# ConcurrentCollections Error while deploying Xamarin iOS Application

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin application build that uses Xamarin Forms along with following settings iOS and droiod project.

Droid project build and runs properly.

However, iOS project build appropriately but while deploying this to iPhone it gives following excpetion.

/Volumes/HDD/Users/admin/Project/Project/Project/Project.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "ConcurrentCollections.ConcurrentHashSet`1" reference from "ConcurrentCollections, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" (MT2002) (peakR.iOS)

Please let me know what i can do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did you use some third party libraries?

Comment: It uses MapsUI,MVVMCross and Plugin.Geolocator as external library